# Issue with Jest after migrate from Angular 13 to Angular 14

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular14, angular14upgrade

I migrate my Angular app from 13 to 14 and after running my unit test i have seen some new errors.

*Unexpected directive 'MockOfRouterOutlet' imported by the module 'MockOfRouterModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.*

Do i have to do some special configuration on Jest to make it work with angular 14?
Does someone encounter the same kinds of problem?

I have found very few informations on the net about this. Help will be very much appreciate.

Comment: Did you use the `RouterTestingModule`?

Comment: How do you use this and where?
In my unit test, i use both RouterModule and RouterTestingModule.. In my imports section i do RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]).

Comment: [Like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/navbar/src/navbar/navbar.component.spec.ts#L16-L21)